# Why does vuetify3 v-date-picker throws error message?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

I'm trying to use vuetify 3's new v-date-picker component but I get and error and the picker doesn't even show up to me. The same thing happens when it has a v-model and when it doesn't have. Currently this is what I have:

```
<v-date-picker elevation="24" color="primary"></v-date-picker>
```

And I get the following error message:

```
vuetify.mjs?v=0ac4dddc:242 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Invalid time value
    at vuetify.mjs?v=0ac4dddc:242:8
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at getWeekdays (vuetify.mjs?v=0ac4dddc:237:25)
    at Proxy.getWeekdays (vuetify.mjs?v=0ac4dddc:533:12)
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (VDatePickerMonth.mjs?v=0ac4dddc:108:40)
    at renderComponentRoot (chunk-UKZM2QLG.js?v=0ac4dddc:2334:17)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (chunk-UKZM2QLG.js?v=0ac4dddc:7440:46)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (chunk-UKZM2QLG.js?v=0ac4dddc:429:19)
    at instance.update (chunk-UKZM2QLG.js?v=0ac4dddc:7571:17)
    at setupRenderEffect (chunk-UKZM2QLG.js?v=0ac4dddc:7581:5)
```

Does anyone know what can be the problem?

I have also tried to import the "date" composable to vuetify how it is stated in the document, but it just creates another error that there is no `vuetify/date/adapters/vuetify`
My vue version is 3.4.15 and vuetify is 3.5.1
This is how my complete package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@livy/logger": "^1.0.5",
    "@livy/rotating-file-handler": "^1.0.4",
    "@mdi/font": "^7.3.67",
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "@nuxtjs/device": "^3.1.1",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0-rc.6",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/sitemap": "^2.4.0",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.11",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "date-fns-tz": "^2.0.0",
    "mitt": "^3.0.1",
    "nuxt": "^3.9.3",
    "nuxt-proxy": "^0.4.1",
    "nuxt-speedkit": "^3.0.0-next.44",
    "pinia": "^2.1.6",
    "redirect-ssl": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.69.3",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.4.15",
    "vue-cryptojs": "^2.4.5",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5",
    "vuetify": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/js": "^7.3.67"
  }
}
```

And this is my vuetify plugin:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import colors from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors'
import '../assets/variables.scss'
import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/lib/iconsets/mdi-svg'
import { mdiClose, ... } from '@mdi/js'
import { da, de, en, sv, no } from 'vuetify/locale'

const dark = {
    dark: true,
    colors: {
        primary: '#4c95f8',
        secondary: '#424242',
        ...
    },
};

const light = {
    dark: false,
    colors: {
        primary: '#4c95f8',
        secondary: '#424242',
        ...
    },
};


export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    const vuetify = createVuetify({
        ssr: true,
        defaultAssets: false,
        customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
        icons: {
            defaultSet: 'mdi',
            aliases: {
                ...aliases,
                mdiThemeLightDark: mdiThemeLightDark,
                mdiClose: mdiClose,
                ...
            },
            sets: {
                mdi,
            },
        },
        treeShake: true,
        theme: {
            defaultTheme: "light",
            themes: {
                dark,
                light,
            },
        },
        locale: {
            locale: 'da',
            fallback: 'en',
            messages: { da, de, no, en, sv },
        },
    })

    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

And my vite setup from nuxt.config:

```
vite: {
        vue: {
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls,
            },
        },
    },
```

Comment: The error isn't reproducible with just that one line of code. In a properly configured project it just works.  Maybe include your package.json, vuetify config, vite config, etc. as there may be something in the configuration of your project that may reveal what's wrong.

Comment: Okay, I have added the things you've mentioned to my original question